# Select Query for checking either or condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, wso2-esb

I'm using postgresql 9.1 and wish to select some records from table.
Details are as below :
table name : muser
fields to be selected : userid, mailid, phonenumber

I have used query like :

```
SELECT userid, mailid, phonenumber FROM muser WHERE phonenumber = ? OR mailid = ?
```

and it should satisfy following conditions :

1. display a record when both are present
2. display a record when only mailid is present
3. display a record when only phonenumber is present.

Important thing is **userid is unique** . so result should be a single record. I have use filter in my wso2esb tool.and in filter when I have filtered with above conditions, in first two conditions query working properly but in last condition it shows all userid available in table.is the query is incorrect? Or I have to user another clause instead of or clause in query

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: By "present" do you mean present in the records or present as input parameter? In other words: can the `phonenumber` and `mailid` fields be NULL in the table? Can they be empty as argument? And as  Uriil says: please show us sample data and expected output!

Comment: no..they are not empty..i'm taking sample phno and mailid in query and trying to checking either one or both are available in table or not?

Comment: @ Uriil : please check below link..i have posted updated question with inputs and expected output http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422963/select-query-to-check-both-or-either-or-condition

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes: i meant available..i have updated that in question and please check link below for more details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422963/select-query-to-check-both-or-either-or-condition

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes:Yes either both of them are present or either any one of them are present in table..result should be single record because userid is unique

Comment: Even your updated question is not clear. Are `phonenumber` and `mailid` present or not present as replacement for the two `?` (i.e. as arguments to your query) or in the table itself?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `null` as the value of the absent parameter

```
select userid, mailid, phonenumber
from muser
where
    (phonenumber = ? or ? is null)
    and
    (mailid = ? or ? is null)
```

Comment: :thanks for reply.Please check the below link..i have update my question with more details  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422963/select-query-to-check-both-or-either-or-condition

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the `userid` is unique does not mean that the mail ids and the phone numbers are unique. If two users have the same `phonenumber`, which can happen in companies, you will get two users when searching for this phone number. Keep that in mind.

I assume that either both parameters are given or exactly one of the two is missing. In the last case pass `NULL` for the missing parameter.

Lets use the parameters `$1` for the mail id and `$2` for the phone number

```
SELECT
    userid, mailid, phonenumber
FROM
    muser
WHERE
    ($1 IS NULL OR $1 IS NOT NULL AND mailid = $1) AND
    ($2 IS NULL OR $2 IS NOT NULL AND phonenumber = $2)
```