# Select Query to check both or either or condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, wso2-esb

I'm using postgresql 9.1 and wish to select a single record from table. Details are as below :

table name : muser

fields present in table : userid,username,firstname,lastname,phonenumber and mailid

fields to be selected : userid, mailid, phonenumber

request parameter : mailid and phonenumber

conditions should be satisfied:

1. display a record when both are present
2. display a record when only mailid is present
3. display a record when only phonenumber is present.

expected output:

single record (as userid is unique) 
with userid, 
     phonenumber and 
     mailid

both or any one if present.

i have tried the query as :

```
SELECT userid, mailid, phonenumber 
FROM muser 
WHERE phonenumber = ? OR mailid = ?
```

It's working fine for first two conditions but not working for last condition..When i fire query for last condition it gives all records present in query.Why so? Is their any changes in query? or anything else

Comment: What do you mean by *last condition*? I see only 2 where clause elements in the query you supplied.

Comment: i meant when i put only mailid and phonenumber is not present then i got all records present in table

Comment: i required only a single query that should check that is their a record in table that contains phonenumber provided by request or mailid provided by request or a record with both phno and mailid present in table??

Answer (score 1):

When I'm dealing with filter where the value can be any including `null` I'll try add `coalesce()`

```
SELECT userid, mailid, phonenumber 
FROM muser 
WHERE coalesce(phonenumber,'no data') = coalesce(?,'no data') 
OR coalesce(mailid,'no data') = coalesce(?, 'no data');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when you mean "not present", mailid or phonenumber will be `NULL` in database,

```
SELECT userid, mailid, phonenumber 
FROM muser 
WHERE (phonenumber = ? AND (mailid IS NULL OR mailid = ''))
OR ((phonenumber IS NULL OR phonenumber = '') AND mailid = ?)
OR (phonenumber = ? AND mailid = ?)
```

Comment: can you give some more information? E.g., when mailed not present is it actually NULL or blank?

Comment: When mailid is not present.It may be blank

Comment: added empty string check as well, try now

Comment: I don't have access to a database right now, neither I could locate any syntax error there. Conceptually the solution should be like above. But you need to try and resolve any syntax error etc.