# How to handle space of postgresql query in wso2esb and wso2dss

Tags: sql, postgresql, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2esb 4.7.0 and wso2dss 3.1.0 and wish to select some records from table..for that i have write dbs file in dss and it's configuration is like :

```
<query id="Capp_select_emercontactid" useConfig="default">
      <sql>select userid,mailid,phonenumber from muser where phonenumber = ? or mailid = ?</sql>
      <result element="Entries" rowName="Entry">
         <element column="userid" name="userid" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="mailid" name="mailid" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param name="phonenumber" ordinal="1" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="mailid" ordinal="2" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>

 <operation disableStreaming="true" name="Capp_select_emercontactid_op">
      <call-query href="Capp_select_emercontactid">
         <with-param name="phonenumber" query-param="phonenumber"/>
         <with-param name="mailid" query-param="mailid"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
```

I have tried this in try this service section.When i put both conditions true it's working But When i put single condition and another one is blank it showing all records present in table

```
 <p:Capp_select_emercontactid_op xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
      **<p:phonenumber></p:phonenumber>**
    <p:mailid>youtility</p:mailid>
   </p:Capp_select_emercontactid_op>
```

But if  i put blanks space in at phonenumber it's working fine like below..

```
 <p:Capp_select_emercontactid_op xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
          **<p:phonenumber> </p:phonenumber>**
          <p:mailid>youtility</p:mailid>
       </p:Capp_select_emercontactid_op>
```

Why so?
How can i handle this space in esb?Please refer following link for db and query description :
[Select Query to check both or either or condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422963/select-query-to-check-both-or-either-or-condition)

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried keeping default '?' as it is for field which u r keeping blank in try this section and try to hit service. In my dss whether i keep blank,?, or give space i'm getting proper response. i m using dss 3.2.0